# How to deal with error when adding PostGIS to Postgres at runtime

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgres 15.3 installedon a Windows Server. I am trying to create a database in C# using the following code.

```
m_createdb_cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(string.Format("CREATE DATABASE \"{0}\";", 
dbnamelowerstring.Replace(" ", "_").ToLower()));
m_createdb_cmd.Connection = npgConnection;
m_createdb_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
npgConnection.Close();
```

This works like I would expect. When I follow up with this code I get an error that states PostGIS already exists and the spatial_ref_sys table is not created..

```
m_createdb_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE EXTENSION postgis WITH SCHEMA public;";
m_createdb_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When creating a table, PostGres doesn't understand a geometry column.

If I run this same statement in PGAdmin, it does what it should and the spatial_ref_sys table is then created. Then Postgres knows what a geometry column is. Has anyone run into this, and how did you correct it?

Comment: Please show your code and the error produced.

Comment: That was the code. "CREATE EXTENSION postgis WITH SCHEMA public;" used in a NpgsqlCommand object. Doing it in PGAdmin works, so I know the command is ok, it just won't accept it when running it in C#.

Comment: `Create Extension <name>` installs the appropriate named code. This is a one-time operation per database per extension. In this case since the extension already exists you can either trap the error and continue or (better imho) remove the code to create it.

Comment: That is just the deal. It says it is already there before I add it, but it really isn't because it does not know what a geometry field is. If I use PGAdmin to run this same query on that same DB, it works and then understands what a geometry column is and I can use it as such. I am not sure how the PostGIS got in there from just running a "create database <dbname>"